# How to use cocoon gem in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, cocoon-gem

Have been using `cocoon gem` for nested forms in rails 4 & rails 5 apps. Currently, I was updating one of the rails 5.2 app (which is using cocoon gem) to rails 6.

As rails 6 is using webpacker, so I tired to require cocoon javascript in `application.js` file as we used to do in previous versions of rails.

> app/javascript/application.js

```
//= require cocoon
```

But unfortunately, things do not seem to work. Have also tried to import but of course, it's also not working as the cocoon is not available as a javascript package.

Any solution or alternate for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Updated Solution:  Cocoon package has been release so one can easily use this with wepacker**

Inside your Gemfile add the following:

```
gem "cocoon"
```

Add the componanion package

```
yarn add @nathanvda/cocoon
```

and then in your `app/javascripts/packs/application.js` you should add

```
require("jquery")
require("@nathanvda/cocoon")
```

**Old Solution:**

There is this [Pull Request](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/pull/454) on cocoon GitHub repository that worked perfectly for me.

Package.json is provided in this branch so we can use yarn or npm to install package by providing GitHub repo link.

> yarn add github:nathanvda/cocoon#c24ba53

Cocoon package will install and you can check your `package.json` file.

> "cocoon": "github:nathanvda/cocoon#c24ba53"

commit number `#c24ba53` is important, make sure it is included in your `package.json` file

After this, you can import cocoon.js in `application.js` file.

> import "cocoon";

Comment: Not working. Getting error like  "undefined method `link_to_add_association' for"

Comment: @faisalbhatti you'll have to install gem too as we do normally. this is for just the part where we import javascript file

Comment: Actually we should call on appplication.js  " import 'cocoon/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon' "

Answer (score 3):

There is an 'hack' on the cocoon page for this:

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/555

Answer (score 2):

**First:** run

```
yarn add cocoon-js
```

**Second:** add to `application.js`

```
import 'cocoon-js'
```

Comment: What about the `link_to_add_association` and other helper methods?

Answer (score 0):

Install the cocoon rubygem as usual

```
yarn add cocoon-js-vanilla
```

// app/javascript/packs/application.js
At the top of this file do:

```
import "cocoon-js-vanilla";
```

Inspired by: https://github.com/joerodrig/cocoon-js